Econs help regarding National Income Determination Fundamentals
it isn't always a breeze trying to post something questions as my formatting is all in a mess, lmao. I need some help in the basics of NID and hope some econs experts can provide some help in correcting my misconception.

Where the multiplier process is concerned, do we explain the process strictly in terms of increased consumption giving rise to increase income and increased savings, etc?

e.g. Assume MPC= 0.8. An initial injection of \$10 by government into the economy via a project causes an increase in national income by \$10.
The \$10 of increased income is received by the project workers who spend \$0.90 for every dollar of increased income and save \$0.10 for every  dollar of increased income.
The increased consumption of \$9 creates \$9 of additional national income and is received as income by the households who produce consumer goods.
The households who produce consumer goods spend \$0.90 for every dollar of increased income and save \$0.10 for every dollar of increased income.
The increased consumption of \$8.10 creates \$8.10 of increased national income and is received by the next group of households for selling goods and services to the preceding group.
This group repeats the increased consumption and saving..
Multiplier process ends when the total withdrawals equal initial injection.
Here, I am curious to know whether for every round of multiplied increase, are we to specify it is the increased income generated by previous group increased consumption that allows for the next round's rceipt of an increased income or can i say the subsequent round receives an income that is created as $X of increase in income in the economy.Having to keep specifying the increase in income and increase in savings and consumption leads me to wonder if my description is already flawed..
